# I want to add lower limit constraints in portfolio optimization in Optaplanner exercise

Tags: optimization, optaplanner, portfolio

I want to add lower limit constraints in portfolio optimization in Optaplanner 
exercise.

In Portfolio optimization in Optaplanner, we can control ratio limit by controlling sector constraints, and can only control upper limit value which is given as Quantity Maximum.

I've tried 'add lower limit as Quantity Minimum, and change Hardscore by quantity minimum similarly as quantity maximum.' However, I failed to apply it.

Anyway, is there any better way to add lower limit constraints in portfolio optimization in Optaplanner?

Plz Help me!

Comment: Sorry for my poor English skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's for example per region, just add `quantityMillisMinimum` field on `Region`:

```
public class Region extends AbstractPersistable {

    private String name;
    private Long quantityMillisMaximum; // In milli's (so multiplied by 1000)

    // New field
    private Long quantityMillisMinimum; // In milli's (so multiplied by 1000)
}
```

and a score rule to add the hard constraint:

```
// New rule
rule "Region quantity minimum"
    when
        $region : Region($quantityMillisMinimum : quantityMillisMinimum)
        accumulate(
            AssetClassAllocation(region == $region, quantityMillis != null, $quantityMillis : quantityMillis);
            $quantityMillisTotal : sum($quantityMillis);
            $quantityMillisTotal < $quantityMillisMinimum
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext,
                $quantityMillisTotal - $quantityMillisMinimum);
end
```

Are you using portfolio optimization for anything serious? :)

Comment: Thx for answer, Geoffrey. I saw your Q&As in google+ and youtube video.
By the way, I'm trying to add lower limit constraint in sector and edit as below code

// Sector quantity minimum
      Map<Sector, Long> sectorQuantityTotalMap = solution.calculateSectorQuantityMillisTotalMap();
      for (Sector sector : solution.getSectorList()) {
         long available = sector.getQuantityMillisMinimum() - sectorQuantityTotalMap.get(sector);
         if (available > 0) {
            hardScore += available;
         }
      }
However, it doesn't work :(
The result ratio is lower than limit